# using js to scroll to top

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to implement a simple "scroll to top" button on my site.

HTML:

```html
<a href="#" id="scrolltotop"><img src="img/scrolltotop.png"></a>
```

CSS:

```css
#scrolltotop {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
position: fixed;
right: 100px;
bottom: 50px;
display: block;     
}
```

JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('#scrolltotop').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('#scrolltotop').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
$('#scrolltotop').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
    return false;
});
});
```

When I load my page, I see the button there in the right place for a split second, then it is covered by a background of one of my `div`s that is down the page in my HTML structure. In the end, I can't see it anywhere on my page, and when I inspect the element it is in the right spot, just not visible.

Comment: Can you show some of the code where that specific `div` you talk about is in. And the CSS for that `div`? It might indeed like an answer says be the `z-index` but it could be something else. Are you sure you are not scrolling down and the `#scrolltotop` gets faded out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add an initial `display:none;` to `#scrolltotop` like so:

```
#scrolltotop {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 100px;
    bottom: 50px;
    display:none;
}
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Bh7aH/2/)**

When using `fadeIn()` you need to have the element's initial display state set, so that you're not trying to `fadeIn()` an element that's already present.

Comment: Thanks a bunch... if it is not set to display: none; it is visible until you scroll down to the bottom and back up.. then the fade out takes over...

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index: 1000` to the back to top link so it is shown on top of everything.